# informix sql where get data less 60 days old from today

Tags: informix

I need help writing where clause that will restrict my data to only retrieve past 60 days.

```
select 
name
date
from ....
```

where date is 60 days older from today.

Require this in informix sql.

Answer (score 1):

This will obviously need adapted to your environment...
    SELECT name, date from table WHERE date >= TODAY - 60